# Read a file using shell script and make 2 new files based on Name of item

Tags: shell, awk

I have below file with me :-

```
====== 20160606:034441 ====== Mango(Test)
TestName     MangoT
Row  0
Season N
Name Safeda
Location    Delhi

====== 20160606:034441 ====== Mango(Result)
TestName     MangoR
Result  0
No_of_Mango 13
Quantity    2
Quantity    3
Quantity    6
Quantity    0
Quantity    1
Quantity    9
Quantity    54
Quantity    2
Quantity    4
Quantity    6
Quantity    76
Quantity    0
Quantity    99
Price   50
Price   70
Price   40
Price   30
Price   40
Price   30
Price   20
Price   60
Price   70
Price   80
Price   90
Price   30
Price   30


====== 20160606:034441 ====== Mango(Test)
TestName     MangoT
Row  0
Season N
Name Alphonso
Location    Mumbai


====== 20160606:034441 ====== Mango(Result)
TestName     MangoR
Result  0
No_of_Mango 13
Quantity    5
Quantity    3
Quantity    1
Quantity    0
Quantity    7
Quantity    8
Quantity    70
Quantity    3
Quantity    23
Quantity    43
Quantity    734
Quantity    2
Quantity    929
Price   50
Price   70
Price   40
Price   30
Price   40
Price   30
Price   20
Price   60
Price   70
Price   80
Price   90
Price   30
Price   30
```

Now i need two input files from above file based on Mango Name like :-
FileName :- `safeda.txt`

```
TestName     MangoR
Result  0
No_of_Mango 13
Quantity    2
Quantity    3
Quantity    6
Quantity    0
Quantity    1
Quantity    9
Quantity    54
Quantity    2
Quantity    4
Quantity    6
Quantity    76
Quantity    0
Quantity    99
Price   50
Price   70
Price   40
Price   30
Price   40
Price   30
Price   20
Price   60
Price   70
Price   80
Price   90
Price   30
Price   30
```

2nd FileName :- `Alphonso.txt`

```
TestName     MangoR
Result  0
No_of_Mango 13
Quantity    5
Quantity    3
Quantity    1
Quantity    0
Quantity    7
Quantity    8
Quantity    70
Quantity    3
Quantity    23
Quantity    43
Quantity    734
Quantity    2
Quantity    929
Price   50
Price   70
Price   40
Price   30
Price   40
Price   30
Price   20
Price   60
Price   70
Price   80
Price   90
Price   30
Price   30
```

I need to create these 2 files using shell script.

Comment: You can use simple while read line; do... done. And if line begins with name, you change file you are writing in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=""
do_write=0

while read line
do
  case $line in
    ==*Result*) do_write=1
                ;;
      ==*Test*) do_write=0
                filename=""
                ;;
         Name*) [[ $do_write == 0 ]] && filename=${line#Name }.txt
                ;;
            "") # Skip blank lines
                ;;
             *) [[ $do_write == 1 ]] && echo "$line" >> $filename
  esac
done
```

With your input file:

```
$ head -10 input
====== 20160606:034441 ====== Mango(Test)
TestName     MangoT
Row  0
Season N
Name Safeda
Location    Delhi

====== 20160606:034441 ====== Mango(Result)
TestName     MangoR
Result  0
```

We get the results:

```
$ ./parse < input

$ ls
Alphonso.txt  input  parse   Safeda.txt

$ head Alphonso.txt
TestName     MangoR
Result  0
No_of_Mango 13
Quantity    5
Quantity    3
Quantity    1
Quantity    0
Quantity    7
Quantity    8
Quantity    70    

$ head Safeda.txt
TestName     MangoR
Result  0
No_of_Mango 13
Quantity    2
Quantity    3
Quantity    6
Quantity    0
Quantity    1
Quantity    9
Quantity    54
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk '(/=====/){a=0}
       (/\(Result\)\s*$/){a=1; next} 
       ($1=="Name"){n=$2}
       (a==1){print >> n".txt"}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `(/=====/){a=0}` : if the current line matches `======`, set `a` to `0`.
- `(/\(Result\)\s*$/){a=1; next}: if the current line ends with`(Results)`followed by 0 or more whitespace, set`a`to`1` and skip to the next line.
- `($1=="Name"){n=$2}` : if the 1st field is `Name`, set the `n` variable to the value of the 2nd field.
- `(a==1){print >> n".txt"` : if `a` is `1`, print this line into a file called `n` (the Name) with the extension `.txt`.